# SQL Decimal type - Precision and Scale discrepancy

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an attempt to answer another question on here I have created the following data structure and rows:

```
create table [resource] (Name varchar(16),date datetime, project varchar(16),hours int)
INSERT INTO resource
values ('Andy Sandy', '2013-03-02', 'Enhancements',40)
INSERT INTO resource
values('Fred Jones', '2013-10-02', 'Enhancements',40)
```

I have executed the following query:

```
select 
case when sum(hours) > 0 Then
    CAST(SUM(hours) as DECIMAL(5,2))/40
else 0 end as [hours],
[DATE]
from resource group by date
```

The results look like this:

```
Hours           Date
1.000000    2013-03-02 00:00:00.000
1.750000    2013-10-02 00:00:00.000
```

When I casted the hours to a decimal I specified a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.  I don't understand why the number is like this.  If I do not specify a precision and scale then the result is the same.  Why is this?

Comment: I get this with your supplied data:hours                                   DATE
--------------------------------------- -----------------------
1.000000                                2013-03-02 00:00:00.000
1.000000                                2013-10-02 00:00:00.000

Comment: The result of the division is `numeric(9,6)`. Treat 40 as being `numeric(2,0)` then plug the precision and scale into [the formulas in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: $&%^% Silly rules mean I cannot format this reasonablly without losing rep by posting an inappropriate answer.

Comment: The following statement resolves this.  I am thinking about deleting the question: CAST(CAST(SUM(hours) as DECIMAL(5,2))/40 AS Decimal(5,2))

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens, I don't understand your concern.  Please post it in a comment.

Comment: Are you asking why the `Hours` column has so many decimal digits?  If so, note that the division is happening outside the `CAST`, so the result will be `FLOAT`.

Comment: @Bob Duell, yes that is what I am asking.  Could you post an answer so that I can give credit?

Comment: Bob's answer is incorrect. The result is `numeric(9,6)` not `float` as per my earlier comment.

Comment: @Martin Smith, thanks.  Do you know why it is casted into numeric(9,6) by default?

Comment: @w0051977: I can't seem to insert CR into a comment, so my text diagram runs and waraps ucontrollably. I take it didn't see my rant on Meta this morning

Comment: I was just trying to clarify the question and am not competent with SQL-Server to answer.  In the databases I know, such an expression would return a FLOAT.  All DBs are different (I think).  The greater point is to always cast results as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing `numeric(5,2)` / 40.

From [Precision, Scale, and Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
+-----------+------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Operation |          Result precision          |   Result scale *    |
+-----------+------------------------------------+---------------------+
| e1 / e2   | p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1) | max(6, s1 + p2 + 1) |
+-----------+------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Treat 40 as being `numeric(2,0)` as this is the smallest possible decimal representation that preserves the precision and scale.

So

```
p1=5
s1=2,
p2=2
s2=0
```

Then plug that into the formulas from BOL

```
Precision: 5 - 2 + 0 + max(6, 2 + 2 + 1) = 9
Scale: max(6, 2 + 2 + 1)                 = 6
```

So the result is `numeric(9,6)`.

You can also see this from

```
;WITH cte(thing) AS
(
 SELECT CAST(1 as DECIMAL(5,2))/40
)
SELECT thing, 
       sql_variant_property(thing,'basetype') AS basetype,
       sql_variant_property(thing,'precision') AS precision, 
       sql_variant_property(thing,'scale') AS scale, 
       sql_variant_property(thing,'maxlength') AS maxlength
FROM cte
```

Returns

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|  thing   | basetype | precision | scale | maxlength |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| 0.025000 | decimal  |         9 |     6 |         5 |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

(NB: `decimal` and `numeric` are synonyms)

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea there was actual math behind the precision/scale calcs for a calculated column. Great link!

Comment: @KyleHale - [This one has a bit more detail than BOL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your first line i.e. You are doing numeric(5,2) / 40?  I am casting to a DECIMAL not a NUMERIC.

Comment: @w0051977 They are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

How strange. If you run [sp_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)

```
sp_describe_first_result_set N'
select 
case when sum(hours) > 0 Then
    CAST(SUM(hours) as DECIMAL(5,2))/40
else 0 end as [hours],
[DATE]
from resource group by date'
```

You see that the hours column you're returning is being cast as decimal(9,6).

If you change your original cast to, say, DECIMAL(10,6) it recasts it as (14,10). So you think it just adds 4 levels of right-of-decimal precision. Not quite!

Change your divider from 40.0 to 400.0 - now it casts as (15,11) - it adds an extra level of precision based on the divider's precision as well.

Change it to 40.0000 instead (3 extra zeroes) - now it's (20,15). So there's a function at work to determine precision based on both the original value and the divisor.

Every extra level of precision to the right of the decimal adds (2,1) to your original cast. 
Every level of precision to the left adds (1,1) to your original cast.

To return the hours columns as decimal(5,2) you just need to do

```
select 
case when sum(hours) > 0 Then
    CAST(SUM(hours) /40.0 as decimal(5,2))
else 0 end as [hours],
[DATE]
from resource group by date
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work +1.  I tried the following CAST earlier but this did not work: CAST(SUM(hours) /40 as decimal(5,2)).  Why does changing 40 to 40.0 make a difference?

Comment: What is: sp_describe_first_result_set N'?

Comment: @w0051977: Because "/" is integer division, unless one of its arguments forces it to float division.

Comment: @w0051977 I added a link to it in the answer. It's SQL Server's replacement for SET FMTONLY ON/OFF.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Any clue about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780779/how-to-increase-the-default-precision-and-scale-while-loading-data-from-oracle-u

Comment: @Shyam: I don't know anything about spark-sql. However your question seems to confuse *floating point* and *decimal* data types. The point of a *decimal* datatype is that it performs **integer arithmetic**. Floating point types perform **gloating point** arithmetic. They are two very different bit layouts for storing approximations of real and rational numbers. The former keeps *precision* constant as an absolute value while the former keeps it constant as a percentage of current magnitude.